# How does the comparison of rates depend on mutual speed?

Tags: special-relativity

If I'm moving with a considerable fraction of speed of light, the time and any process in my system will be going slower. If B is an outstanding person that is watching me passing by, he will see everything in my system in slow motion. This means he observes less ticks per seconds; thus the ticks are slower or the interval between the ticks is bigger. From my perspective everything is normal and time is not running slower. 
Is it okay to talk about the speed of time in this context? Is it okay to say: "The shorter the interval between two ticks the faster the speed of time."?

Comment: You have to be careful how you word this question because of reference frames in relativity. For example "any process in my system will be going slower" isn't true if you are talking about your own reference frame. But from an observer B's perspective this is true.

Comment: BobbyPi: "_[...] Is it okay to talk about the speed of time in this context?_" -- In my answer below I replied to this that "[I consider such talk intolerable. (This is indeed only a statement of my opinon, which is however informed by didactic experience.)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/262805)". But I'm glad you asked, of course; therefore +1. (Actually, I'd find it preferrable that you rephrase the title of your post accordingly; which should be possible in principle for you as original poster, and hopefully also in practice, i.e. without hurdles in terms of required reputation count.)

Comment: @user12262: At first, tanks for your detailed answer. What title would be appropriate in your opinion?

Comment: BobbyPi: "_thanks for your detailed answer._" -- Glad to help; thanks in turn. "_What title would be appropriate [...]?_" -- Looking at the actual questions in your original text (one of them quoted above) I'd've titled: "How to speak appropriately about time, durations, and rates in consideration of observers moving wrt. each other?". (But that's just typical me ..., and that may be depreciated.) Also, I find the present title akward as it stands. If I understand it at all, I'd put that rather as: "How does the comparison of rates depend on mutual speed?". (So this I'd suggest, if you agree.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I'm moving with a considerable fraction of speed of light, the time and any process in my system will be going slower.

That's an improper, careless, lazy description ("*slower*" -- in comparison to what??).

> If B is an outstanding person that is watching me passing by, he will see everything in my system in slow motion.

Taken literally, that's not correct either.
Instead, the rate of what B (being stationary as a member of an inertial system) sees of you (or A), moving straight along B's line of sight ("${\text{LoS}}$") through B's system at speed $c~\beta_{\text{LoS}} = v_{\text{LoS}}$; towards B, right past B, and finally away from B, is related to your own (proper) rate by the [Longitudinal Doppler factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect#Motion_along_the_line_of_sight) which is derived to be $$\frac{f_B[~\text{observing }A~]}{f_{A\text{ (proper)}}} = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \beta_{\text{LoS}}}{1 + \beta_{\text{LoS}}}},$$
which is less than $1$, therefore corresponding to (mutually) "*seeing slow motion*", or (mutually) "red shifted", for $\beta_{\text{LoS}} > 0$ (i.e. in the course of A and B finally receding from each other);
but larger than $1$, therefore corresponding to (mutually) "*[seeing fast forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-lapse_photography#Terminology)*", or (mutually) "blueshifted", for $\beta_{\text{LoS}} < 0$ (i.e., by the suitable sign convention, in the course of A and B initially approaching from each other).

This is to be contrasted with the [Transverse Doppler factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect#Transverse_Doppler_effect)
$$\frac{f_B[~\text{projected from successive meetings with}A~]}{f_{A\text{ (proper)}}} = \sqrt{1 - \beta^2},$$
which characterizes (mutual) time dilation directly, as the Lorentz factor $\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}$, and where the members of B's inertial system infer the value of frequency $f_B[~\text{projected from successive meetings with}A~]$ by determinations of simultaneity between each other.

> This means he [B] observes

... or rather, the members of B's system determine by simultaneity projection ...

> less ticks [of A] per seconds

... **than**: A counted properly (him- or herself) likewise *per seconds*; **provided** that what A and what B separately and properly mean by "one *second*" are in fact equal durations.

Of course, it can be measured, trial by trial, whether equality is the case, or whether there is any difference;
by first (separately) determining the value of the mutual speed parameter $\beta$, and then calculating and applying the appropriate factors described above to compare $f_{A\text{ (proper)}}$ and the corresponding $f_{B\text{ (proper)}}$.

> Is it okay to talk about the speed of time in this context?

I consider such talk intolerable. (This is indeed only a statement of my opinon, which is however informed by didactic experience.) Instead, it is perfectly adequate and correct to consider and to speak of rates, as described above, which are of course understood to be proper.

Answer (score 0):

When one compares the spacetime coordinates between own rest frame and some other inertial frame, the time coordinate is transformed as such:

$$ t = \frac{\tau}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $$

where $\tau$ is the proper time and $t$ is the time in some inertial frame. I think you can lazily but carefully refer to the following quantity as "the speed of time" in some frame with respect to your own rest frame:

$$ \frac{d t}{d \tau} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $$

Which is, of course a [Lorentz factor](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lorentz_factor) of the boost.